# Eureka's hsqldb overriding MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, hsqldb, netflix-eureka

I have a Spring Boot project that currently consists of three microservices (all of them are maven children of the mentioned project), namely:

- **eureka-server** : as the name says, it's simply a Eureka project that works as a server for registering other microservices
- **user-server** : a project that holds a 'monolithic stack' (model, DAO, service and controller). Here is where the problem is. More on this later.
- **web-server** : a project that contains the AngularJS application and a controller that is accessible from AngularJS and that communicates with the user-server module.

Eureka forces me to include a *hsqldb* dependency in the parent pom in order to launch the three mentioned applications.

The problem is that I was using MySQL in *user-server* and hsqldb has somehow overriden the MySQL data source.

In other words, the database engine of user-server is now hsqldb and I want to keep working with MySQL, and if I remove the dependency, the application will obviously not launch.

Is there any way to solve this and work with, maybe, two databases in user-server?

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to get it working. I'll just post it here in case someone faces a similar problem.

It seems that application.properties wasn't being read when launching the application because telling Spring Boot which .yml configuration file for Eureka should be read, it was overriden.

In the .yml file of the microservice I wasn't able either to set the datasource to MySQL, so the solution was to hardcode the datasource properties when launching the microservice, as follows:

System.setProperty("spring.datasource.platform","mysql");
System.setProperty("spring.datasource.url","jdbc:mysql...");